# Updating window (Directx) when Screen not present

Tags: windows, server, directx, virtual, rdp

I got pretty uncommon problem. I have a few virtual servers running Windows Server 2012 and bots playing game. This game uses DirectX5 or DirectX9 or OpenGL engine. Everything is fine when you connect to server via RDP, I start bot and it plays the game by it's own. But as soon as I close RDP I find in logs that bot is not anymore playing the game and I think that the reason is that when I close RDP the screen/monitor/anything where directx cloud output it's rendering is not present so it probably thinks this way "Okay no any monitor (RDP) connected so I won't update or render game". I think that even when I minimize RDP then game is not refreshing anymore. I'm not sure if this is the DirectX issue that is not rendering when screen is not present but what else could be? Is there a way I could force DirectX to render the game even when screen is not present?